# Why don't I get the String value returned from apex in js in the LWC project?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

In the `js` class, I call the `apex` `getCityCurrentUser()` method, which should return me a string, but I end up with an empty value. But the `apex` class works fine and gets my value from the database, which I try to return to `js` as a string (I make a log of this operation and see that my code exactly fills the string with the value I need). What's wrong?

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getCityCurrentUser() {
    if (!Schema.sObjectType.User.fields.City.isUpdateable()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        List<User> currentUser = [SELECT City FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
        String cityUser;
        for (User u : currentUser) {
            cityUser = u.City;
        }
        System.debug('currentCity ' + cityUser);
        return cityUser;
    }
}
```

This is a log entry: `USER_DEBUG [98]|DEBUG|currentCity Mogilev`

```
connectedCallback() {
        let userCity = getCityCurrentUser();
        console.log('userCity: ' + getCityCurrentUser());
        performCallout({location: 'Minsk' }).then(data => {
            this.mapMarkers = [{
                location: {
                    Latitude: data['cityLat'],
                    Longitude: data['cityLon']
                },
                title: data['cityName'],
            }];
            this.result = data;
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

This is a log entry: `userCity: [object Promise]`

This is a log entry (JSON.stringify): `userCity: {}`

Comment: Can you please show how "getCityCurrentUser" is defined in your LWC and note that the connectedCallback may well be invoked before any wires. Why are you doing this in the connectedCallback? Please explain your LWC's lifecycle. Please [edit] the question to add these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    let userCity = getCityCurrentUser();
```

An imperative Apex call returns a Promise, because it has to go to the server and back. JavaScript won't wait by default, giving you just the Promise, so you have to wait until the Promise resolves.

You have two options here. You can either use Promise.then, or await.

```
// If you use await, the function must be async.
async connectedCallback() {
  try {
    // Waits here
    let userCity = await getCityCurrentUser();
    // rest of code here
  } catch(e) { 
    // Handles any "reject()" from the Promise
  }
```

Or...

```
connectedCallback() {
  getCityCurrentUser()
  .then((userCity) => performCallout({location: 'Minsk' }))
  .then(data => {
      // rest of code //
  })
  .catch(e => this.dealWithTheError(e));
```

Or...

```
connectedCallback() {
  getCityCurrentUser()
  .then((userCity) => {
    performCallout({location: 'Minsk' })
    .then(data => {
      // rest of code //
    })
  })
  .catch(e => this.dealWithTheError(e));
```

Any way you slice it, you need to wait for the asynchronous response in order to continue.